# Paperclip creating attachment even if nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

I've been using Paperclip within an application for about 6 months now.  Using active admin / formtastic I've got an interface for adding images to a model. Up until now when there was no image attachment being created automatically - since the upgrade it seems there is - even if attempting to set to nil before saving.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: what values do you see in the table for the attachment?

Comment: Hmm I might've jumped the gun here; even though there IS a Paperclip::Attachment object with a default_url / url  -- BUT if I do image.present?  it's coming back false.. so perhaps something changed or maybe I've just been mistaken til now?

Comment: to detect the present of attachment in a record, I do `if @post.picture_file_size != nil` and that is working out well